# "Summoning something into life" vs. "summoning something to life"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, american-english, british-english, to-into

What is the difference between the following?

> - Summoning ... **into** life
> - Summoning ... **to** life

If it helps, I want to use the word *idea* in the place of dots so it's like:

> - Summoning your ideas **into** life.
> - Summoning your ideas **to** life.

*Summoning* in this context is supposed to mean that someone is creating, building, rising someone other ideas; bringing it to reality, crafting it.

I wasn't able to find an answer to this question. What is the difference between these two versions and which one is correct (or perhaps both are?)

Is one more American English and one British English?

Comment: They both sound wrong to me. You summon things that already exist and will come when you call for them. This doesn't really work for ideas.

Comment: What @Peter said. You can talk of *bringing your ideas to life*, but that has a different meaning - your ideas will have already existed, and you're talking about doing something that will make them more startling/relevant/interesting/etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the real meaning of the world "summon"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this. If I am understanding your question, I think you might actually want to say that you are *bringing ideas to life*, instead of summoning them to life. Google the phrase "bring to life" and you get lots of alternatives and explanations. One site does say "bring to life" is an American idiom.

Comment: I guess I'll stick with the "bring your ideas to life". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To summon essentially means to call, or to send for. When we summon something we call it to appear before us. So the right expression with "**summon**" would be "**summon *to***", not "**summon *into***".

However, I don't think that summon is the best word. You suggest meanings like create, build, raise, craft. As JLG says, "[**bring to life**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+life)" is one natural idiom. You could also say "**bring life to** sth." or "**breathe life into** sth.".

Comment: Until now I thought that "summon" can mean both: 1. to appear, like in: 'summon to show in the court' or 2. to be created, born, like in: 'summoning creatures to life'. Thanks for your answer and pointing other idioms (I especially like 'breathe life into sth'.)